# how to index mysql using dataimportHandler programatically?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

i want to index mysql using solr dataimportHandler programatically.the apache solr interface works fine.but i don't know how to implement that in my java code.Can anyone help me by showing me an example?thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

In linux, you can use `curl` or `wget` and invoke the URL:

`http://HOST:PORT/CORE/dataimport?command=full-import`

or

`http://HOST:PORT/CORE/dataimport?command=delta-import`